# Looking to update jquery variable from form to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've seen a number of questions like mine here but none of the answers have worked for me and my JS is subpar.

I'm using SimpleWeather.js and all I want to do is make a form field to update the zip code. I can get the zip variable from the form but I can't get it to update the getWeather() function and therefore update the weather.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the important parts of the code.

HTML

```
<form>
  <input id="zip" type="text" name="zip">
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  getWeather(); 
  setInterval(getWeather, 600000);
});

var zip = "90001";
$('#zip').on("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var zip = $("#zip").val();  
  getWeather();
});

function getWeather() {
  $.simpleWeather({
    location: zip,
    woeid: '',
    unit: 'f',
    success: function(weather) {
...
```

I've got a codepen at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRgBBb

Comment: I don't see any documentation at simpleweatherjs.com. It looks like a search results page.

Comment: You need to make `zip` a global variable, and also give it a default value before the user changes the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the `zip` variable to the function, and pass the updated value to the function as well.

```js
const zip = "90001";

$(document).ready(function() {  
  getWeather(zip); 
  setInterval(getWeather, 600000);
});
$('#zip').on("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var new_zip = $("#zip").val();  
  getWeather(new_zip);
});

function getWeather(zip_code) {
  alert("Current zip: " + zip_code);
  //$.simpleWeather({
  //  location: zip_code,
  //  woeid: '',
  //  unit: 'f',
  //  success: function(weather) {
      // do your stuff  
  //  }
  //});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="zip">
<button>change</button>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much.

Comment: I know this comment is really late but I just noticed that when the setInterval(getWeather) function updates its grabbing the original zip variable not the updated one. Any chance you can help with that as well? Thanks.

Comment: Just pass the new one to the function inside the `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of small errors... You are defining the `zip` variable twice. You only need to define it once, otherwise it will stay stuck at `90001`. In your CodePen you were not calling `getWeather()` after grabbing the zip. Last, you want to set your submit button to `type="button"` to prevent the form from being submitted in the classic HTML way:

```
var zip = "90001";
$('#zip').on("change", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //var zip = $("#zip").val();  
  zip = $("#zip").val();
  getWeather();
});


<input type="button" id="setZip" name="setZip" value="Set Zip"/>
```